# How to protect a fragile command in a moving argument? The case of macro containing \ifthenelse in \caption

Tags: macros, expansion

This script works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
  \newcommand{\capt}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{ORIG}}
               {original}
               {optimised}
  }

}
\begin{document}
\foo{ORIG}
\end{document}
```

However, when the macro `\capt` is inserted into a `\caption` in a `figure` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
  \newcommand{\capt}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{ORIG}}
               {original}
               {optimised}
  }
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\capt}
  \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\foo{ORIG}
\end{document}
```

the error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal
```

What is the problem?

I am probably observing a symptom of a general feature. Therefore, help is appreciated how to form the title and this question to reflect the more general nature of this issue.

Comment: Does it work with `\protect\capt`?

Comment: @samcarter, yes `\protect\capt` helps.

Comment: this is typical "fragile command in moving argument" error (which is what `\protect` is designed to protect you from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you do the intermediate step of defining `\capt`; however, the problem is that `\ifthenelse` is a fragile command, so it should be protected when in a caption or other moving argument.

There are better ways that don't require acrobatics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \newcommand{\capt}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{ORIG}
      {original}
      {optimised}%
  }%
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{\capt}
  \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}

\foo{ORIG}

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to protect the end of lines which could generate spaces in output.