# Protect fragile variable in file path. Case of \ifthenelse in \includegraphics{}

Tags: macros, expansion, ifthenelse, protected-macro, fragile

In this script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myfigure}[1]{%                                                                                                                   
  \def\mydirectory{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{first}}{dir1}{dir2}}

  my directory is \mydirectory

  \begin{figure}
%    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{\protect\mydirectory/mypic.pdf}%                                                                  
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%                                                                                 
    \caption{picture in \protect\mydirectory}
  \end{figure}

}

\begin{document}
\myfigure{first}
\end{document}
```

I `\protect` the fragile variable `\mydirectory` in `\caption` - see comments to [How to protect a fragile command in a moving argument? The case of macro containing \ifthenelse in \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454770/how-to-protect-a-fragile-command-in-a-moving-argument-the-case-of-macro-contain).

However, when I provide:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{\mydirectory/mypic.pdf}
```

the classical symptoms of a fragile `\ifthenelse` appear:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal 
                  {first}{first}
```

that are not cured even by `\protect`:

`\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{\protect\mydirectory/mypic.pdf}`

How to protect a fragile variable in a file path?

Comment: Ifthenelse is not expandable.  You can't use it in this place.

Comment: I think it should by now be clear to you that `\ifthenelse` ***doesn't*** work by pure expansion. A method with `\ifstreq` similar to one I suggested for another case will work flawlessly.

Comment: This can not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use `ifthenelse` but if you use it (or any other test mechanism) you want `\mydirectory` to expand to the directory name, not to a complicated sequence of assignments and tests that may eventually typeset a directory name.

so

```
\newcommand{\myfigure}[1]{%                                                                                                                   
  \def\mydirectory{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{first}}{dir1}{dir2}}
```

can not possibly work, you would need

```
\newcommand{\myfigure}[1]{%                                                                                                                   
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{first}}%
   {\def\mydirectory{dir1}}%
   {\def\mydirectory{dir2}}%
}
```

so that the definition of `\mydirectory` is either `dir1` or `dir2`.

Comment: As you define `\mydirectory` in `{\def\mydirectory{dir1}}` will not `\mydirectory` live only inside the scope `{}`?

Comment: @Viesturs no: `{}`:  that delimit macro arguments do not form a group.

Comment: Is it advisable to use `\newcommand` in place of `\def`?

Comment: @Viesturs well `\newcommand` wouldn't work after the first time, you could give it an initial definition and then use `\renewcommand` so it always redefines, but no point really, it just makes it check every time that the command is already defined, when you have set it up to be defined.